# How check datas if exists, in EF on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

How do you implement the checking condition in Entity Framework if the given value exists in the database?

I made it:

```
using (eDoctorEntities db = new eDoctorEntities())
    {
       if (db.Pacjents.Any( x => x.Pesel == PESEL.Text))
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Podany PESEL istnieje w bazie");
         }
       else if (db.Kontakts.Any( x => x.email == Email.Text))
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Podany e-mail istnieje w bazie");
         }
       else if (db.Kontakts.Any( x => x.Telefon == Telefon.Text))
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Podany telefon istnieje w bazie");
         }
       else
         {
            db.Pacjents.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Zarejestrowano !");
         }
     }
```

but it doesn't work :( Please help me.

Code Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNDp2.png)

with error exception INNER DETAILS:

---

> SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Adres'. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Adres'. The duplicate key value is
>   (0). The statement has been terminated.

---

Model database:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJDSi.png)

Comment: What does not work? Are you getting always to default else block?

Comment: Right @user1672994 thank you. I forgot to add the error code, I will correct it soon.

Comment: What is InnerException?

Comment: SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Adres'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Adres'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: `builder.Entity<Adres>().Property(p => p.Id_Adres).ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to store data to a table (Adres) where that value exists in this case '0'. It doesn't look like you check for that value (Id_Adres) at all in these if statements.

It also might be that you have not set up that value (Id_Adres) to increment automatically in your database, so it takes the unset value in your model which defaults to 0. You either need to set the PK ID manually or have it automatically increment each time data is added.

@Fabio has given the right comment to do this.

Comment: I thought about this solution to automatically number the ID but then rejects the second connection with the foreign key and the program sees it as two values, how to do it accordingly? After all, I will not be adding the ID manually as the program will be stable to use. He should number himself ... and here's the problem too. Will you help?

Comment: What sort of error does it give with the second connection?

Comment: The other solution is to make your Id_Adir optional

Comment: Thank you @HenryMigo :) Previously, instead of setting the autonumbering for the primary key, I set this for the foreign key. Everything works stably! Programming beer for you :D